# How to properly set up a json config file so that it can be used to replace hardcoded values in python program

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to modify my python method so that its reading values from a separate json config file.

I have a separate valid json file that looks like this `testtok.json`:

```
    {
        "email" : "user@domain.com",
        "audience" : "http://someaudience.com",
        "jti" : "MYJTI1234",
        "name" : "John Smith",
        "humid" : "ABC1234"
    }
```

I want to pass in those values to my function here:

```
def tokengen(self, privatekey):
    with open('config/testtok.json', 'r') as config:
        data = json.load(config)
    try:
        """Simulate Token Manager creating a token"""
        email = config["email"]
        audience = config["audience"]
        jti = config["jti"]
        name = config["name"]
        humid = config["humid"]


        #email = "user@domain.com"
        #audience = "http://someaudience.com"
        #jti = "MYJTI1234"
        #name = "John Smith"
        #humid = "ABC1234"

        """Time Component"""
        timestamp = testdate()
        timestamp.now()
        issued = int(time.time())
        expires_in=2400             
        expires = issued + expires_in   
        
        additional_headers = {
                "alg": "RS256",
                "typ": "JWT"    
        }
        
        payload = {
            "iss": email,       
            "sub": email,
            "aud": audience,
            "iat": issued,
            "nbf": issued,      
            "exp": expires,     
            "jti": jti,
            "name": name,
            "humid": humid,
            "email": email
        }

        self.testtoken = jwt.encode(payload, privatekey, algorithm="RS256", headers=additional_headers).decode("utf-8")
        valid_response = {'validation' : 'VALID', 'ts' : timestamp.utc_datetime_str, 'test_token' : self.testtoken}
        return(valid_response)

    except Exception as ex:
        invalid_response =  {'validation' : 'INVALID', 'ts' : timestamp.utc_datetime_str, 'test_token' : self.testtoken}
        return(invalid_response)
```

I'm seeing this error and unclear how to troubleshoot this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testTokClass.py", line 25, in tokengen
    config["email"]
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there a better way to do this? Ideally, I would like to have the config file as json. Thanks.

Comment: The JSON is read into `data`, not `config`.

Comment: @KenY-N - you are absolutely right. Overlooked it. I will accept your answer if you want to post it. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th problem is that the `config` is a file handle; in the line `data = json.load(config)` the JSON is read from the file pointed to by `config` and into the `data` variable.

So, just change:

```
email = config["email"]
```

to:

```
email = data["email"]
```

And similarly for the next four lines.